# Initialize UITableView dynamically

Tags: uitableview, tableview, cell

I have a question: how can I initialize a UITableView dynamically ?

Indeed, I have a custo cell with 3 labels and 1 checkbox. In my tableView, I have two sections. Just for testing, I put manually:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 2;
}
```

But if a check a checkbox on a visible cell, the next checkbox which will appear if I scroll will be checked too, but I don't want!

And I would like to make a class with 3 labels and a checkbox like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *label1;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *label2;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *label3;
@property(assign) BOOL *checked;

@end
```

and initialize my UITableView dynamically by using this class (array with objects of this class) but I don't know how to do this.

Thank you for you help! :D

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the free Sensible TableView framework and add the three labels like this:

```
SCTableViewSection *section = [SCTableViewSection sectionWithHeaderTitle:@"Title"];
[section addCell:[SCLabelCell cellWithText:@"Label 1"];
[section addCell:[SCLabelCell cellWithText:@"Label 2"];
//etc.
```